# Filter Query (OData) in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a simple logic app to send email if the a field is true.
The flow is:
    `Get Items From SPO (1) > Filter Array (2) > Send Email (3)`

(1): This step, I want to have a quick filter to limit records returned from SharePoint Online:
    `"queries": { "$filter": "preproccessed eq true" }`

(2)(3): another filter applied, then send email

 The (2) & (3) run just fines, but the (1) doesn't work at all, all records returned regardless of the filter. I even tried this:
`"queries": { "$filter": "preproccessed eq 1" }` 
But it doesn't work.

Anyone has any ideas what I missed here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the OData filter is not supported correctly by the SharePoint Online connector, resulting in all rows being returned regardless of the specified filter condition.

As a workaround, you can use the `Filter array` card to filter the records in the Logic App itself (or use the `Query` action type if you are authoring your logic directly in code view).

```
{
  "type": "Query",
  "inputs": {
    "from": "@body('Get_items')?['value']",
    "where"": "@equals(item()?['preproccessed']?['Value'], 1)"
  },
  "runAfter": { "Get_items": [ "Succeeded" ] },
}
```