# How to write an odata time period filter in a logic app to access Outlook Calendar events?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to get events that start today out of an Outlook calendar. I don't know how to translate the format of the queries used in the API calls into that which the Logic app expects.

I've tried things like

- `'start' ge '2020-03-19-T07:33:33.707Z' and 'start' le '2020-03-26T07:33:33.707Z'` which I basically made up
- a number of variations based on [this answer](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-Query-Filter-Date-Range/td-p/192270).
- and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321088/filter-query-odata-in-logic-app) was too early to support odata queries

[image]

The data is a list of objects that look like this, according to the logic app's post-run viewer:

```
{
    "subject": "Working elsewhere (Not in the office)",
    "start": "2020-03-18T21:00:00.0000000",
    "end": "2020-03-18T21:00:00.0000000",
    "body": "plenty of writing",
    "isHtml": true,
    "responseType": "notResponded",
    "responseTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
    "id": "AAMkAGJkMGY5MTQzLWVhNDAzzAAAHYoGQAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-03-19T02:44:49.558788+00:00",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-19T02:44:49.7419829+00:00",
    "organizer": "Clazbo@bvn.com.au",
    "timeZone": "UTC",
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "categories": [],
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAxxD&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "requiredAttendees": "clazbo@bvn.com.au;",
    "optionalAttendees": "wherebot@bvn.com.au;",
    "resourceAttendees": "",
    "location": "",
    "importance": "low",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "recurrence": "none",
    "recurrenceEnd": null,
    "numberOfOccurences": null,
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 960,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "showAs": "free",
    "responseRequested": false
  },
```

There are two linked parts to this question:

- How do I structure the query? What's its syntax?
- How do I keep the date window rolling (I assume that it's something like `start ge formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd') and start le formatDateTime(utcnow() + 1,'yyyy-MM-dd')`)

Comment: Hi Ben, may I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution works, could you please mark the answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the filter query as below to do this operaion:

```
Start/DateTime ge '2020-03-01T08:00' and Start/DateTime le '2020-03-25T08:00'
```

Of if you don't want the time, it's ok if use the query below:

```
Start/DateTime ge '2020-03-01' and Start/DateTime le '2020-03-25'
```

If you want to use utcnow() in logic app, please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

The two expressions of formatDateTime() in the screenshot are:

```
formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

```
formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), 7),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Please pay attention to the symbol `'` before and after the `formatDateTime()` expression in screenshot.

Hope it helps~